# Alternative Factorization using SVD (U Z V = E) such that det(U) = det(V) = +1

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, svd, factorization

I'm using the python library numpy to compute the svd of a matrix

```
import numpy
E = numpy.array( [[ -1.53796077e-07,  -8.32829326e-06,   1.20315886e-02]
                  [  9.99043253e-06,   5.28004707e-07,   1.42958076e-01]
                  [ -1.70318163e-02,  -1.43960577e-01,   1.00000000e+00]] )
U, Z, V = numpy.linalg.svd(E)
print "det(U) =", det(U)
print "det(V) =", det(V)
```

I get U, Z, V such that:

```
det(U) = 1
det(V) = -1
```

Is it possible to find an alternative factorization for which both U,V are  in SO(3) such that

```
det(U) = 1
det(V) = 1
```

If it is possible:

How can such a factorization be found for an arbitrary Matrix E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply multiply V and Z for `-1*np.eye(3)`